# How to change\remove the space before the chapter "NUMBER" as heading (of thesis format)

Tags: spacing, header-footer, titles

I am using a template to write my thesis and trying to remove the space before the chapter number of each chapter. Here is part of the .cls that I guess I have to modify to change the heading's height:

```
% Headings and headers.

\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}

\RequirePackage[tiny, md, sc]{titlesec}

\setlength{\headheight}{5pt}

\pagestyle{plain}

\RequirePackage{titling}
```

If I change {\headheight}{15pt} to a smaller value it changes the height of all pages by only 1-2 mm!!

Do you have any idea how to fix this? thank you in advance!

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example. Also note, that you should never change a class file.

Comment: Well, here is the start:                                                           
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{Dissertate}[2014/03/25 v2.0 Dissertate Class]
\LoadClass[12pt, oneside, letterpaper]{book}                                                               
 And, here is the link provided :https://awesomeopensource.com/project/suchow/Dissertate

Comment: Please adjust your original code and use the styling possibilities provided by the editor (code section and so on). You'll get help much easier and faster the easier and faster we understand and are able to reproduce your issue(s).

Answer (score 2):

Just replace the line:

```
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace*{-0.5\baselineskip}}
```

with:

```
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace{0em}}
```

BTW: `\headheight` defines the pagehead, not the headings.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, unfortunately it did not work, I guess I should change my question to: why the chapters start in the middle of the page? I need to move the start of the chapter up (which includes the chapter number) , do you have any idea how to change that? thank you.

Comment: @zizoojiloo I updated the answer...

Comment: Thank you @keth-tex, it worked!!

Comment: @zizoojiloo if you think that answer helped you, it's more helpful on this website to "Accept" it.